# Delete overlapping Instances

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I managed to translate instances from the vertices of a sphere to the vertices of another object.
Unfortunately I have some overlapping instances that look ugly in the rendered animation.
Now, I didn't quite understand why some of my instances land on the same vertex of the second object, whereas some of the vertices of the second object remain empty.

However, I'd just like to find a way to delete instances if their END location is the same of other instances.
I tried with the delete geometry, but I can't figure out how to compare the troublesome END positions.

I'm attaching a screenshot of the nodes and the blend file.

[image: nodes]

https://easyupload.io/lzfqh3